# If we can invoke browser prompt dialog box with multi inputs fields and custom note?

Tags: javascript, browser, client

People say we cannot customize DOM prompt box, but I have seen servers like xampp admin login page provide multi inputs dialog box. If we can make our own?

For example like this one:

[image]

Comment: It's an HTTP authentication prompt, not a modified alert or confirm. Bottom line: you can't customize browser prompts.

Comment: @timenomad I see. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate the browsers prompt, but you can create your own custom prompt easily. Here's a dummy for you:

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 30px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p>
    Jolly rogers hobble from graces like big plunders.
  </p>
  <p>
    To the sour lettuce add celery, herring, coconut milk and cored zucchini.
  </p>
  <input >
  <input >
  <button>
    Click me!
  </button>
</div>
```